# Android export a list of all installed apps

Tags: html, text, export

Samsung Galaxy s10e

I just want to export a simple list of all my installed apps.  It can be in the form of an .html file, text or Word document.  Links could be included, but it doesn't have to be fancy.

I've searched for an answer